# Prime number theorem, proof error

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-verification

Can someone help me find where I made an error in this attempted proof

And from there, give me some advice on what I can do to fix it

$$M(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)$$
$$\psi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)=\sum_{n\leq x}\ln(n)*\mu(n)=\sum_{n\leq x}\ln(n)M{\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}$$
$$\ln(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\ln(x)\delta_{n,1}=\sum_{n\leq x}\ln(x)(1*\mu(n))=\sum_{n\leq x}\ln(x)M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$

So that,

$$\psi(x)-\ln(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\ln\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\psi(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}\ln\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)M\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)}\right)$$

So that,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\psi(x)}{x}=\int_{0}^1\ln(x)M\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=\int_{1}^\infty\frac{-\ln(x)M(x)}{x^2}dx$$

But by the mellin transform for the mertens function we have that,

$$\frac{1}{s\zeta(s)}=\int_{1}^\infty\frac{M(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx$$
$$\implies-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{s\zeta(s)^2}-\frac{1}{s^2\zeta(s)}=\int_{1}^\infty\frac{-\ln(x)M(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx$$

$$\implies1=\int_{1}^\infty\frac{-\ln(x)M(x)}{x^2}dx$$

And so, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\psi(x)}{x}=1$$

Comment: I'd like to see a careful justification of the implied claim that $M(1/x) \ln x$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0,1]$.  Since $\int_0^1 (1/x) \ln x$ is divergent, this strikes me as rather delicate and requiring something of the strength of $M(n) = o(n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in the comment, you have to prove that the function $M(1/x) \ln(x)$ is Rieman-integrable, but it is not since Riemann-integrable (on a compact interval) is equivalent to bounded and continuous almost everywhere (cf [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral)). I don't know if this can be salvaged by using the fact that you have a *specific* Riemann sum.

Moreover, to prove that
$$(1) \quad \lim_{s \to 1} \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(x)M(x)}{x^{s+1}} dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(x)M(x)}{x^2} dx,$$
you will have to show that $|M(x)|=O(x^{1-\delta})$ some $\delta>0$, which is almost equivalent to the fact that $\zeta$ has no zero in $\{ Re> 1-\delta \}$ (I think no such $\delta$ has been proved to exist).

Comment: Your statement about Riemann integrability isn't quite right: on a *closed, bounded* interval Riemann integrability is equivalent to bounded and continuous *almost* everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The first equation RHS and LHS is according *Mertens* himself and fine:
$$\psi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\ln(n)M{\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}$$

But the second equation, to be cautious:
$$\ln(x)=\dots=\sum_{n\leq x}\ln(x)M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$

because

$$\psi(x)\ne \ln(x)$$

Why not using Stirling's formula (up to $O(\ln(N))$) then see further.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to communicate both of the aforementioned formula hold for all real $x$

Comment: when turning from sums to integrals, did you really care about the inner sum of $M(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)$. Honestly I can not realise in details how you get your first integral. But may be this is my weakness. Glad to know how you did?

Comment: @al-Hwarizimi $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})=\int_{0}^1f(x)dx$$ For 'some' functions $f(x)$ this is just the limiting case of a reimann sum

Comment: But how can $M(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)$ be such a "some" function, when $n\le x$ and at the same time $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: They approach the same thing, I could have fixed $x$ as an integer $n$ and then re-wrote it as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\psi(n)}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\ln(\frac{k}{n})M(\frac{1}{(\frac{k}{n})})=\int_{0}^1\ln(x)M(\frac{1}{x}) dx$$

Comment: I mean it this way, write out $M$ and see how $n$ does when $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\psi(n)}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\ln‌​(\frac{k}{n}) \sum_{n\leq x}\mu(\frac{1}{(\frac{k}{n})})$$

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say, also were dealing with the mertens function not the mobius function

Comment: see please second answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In my comment, I just introduced your first equation (Mertens) into the fifth equation RHS. You will then get my equation above. Then I do not see a clear justification how to come from my equation above (taking $\mu$ and $n$ behaviour into account) to your first and then (!!) second integral. I feel you are trying in this step to run Perron's formula, but cannot follow the detailed steps. In this step practically you try to mimic a (semi-)Mellin transform. Later you set up the comonly known Mellin transform of the Chebychev function again (via $\zeta$), and compare and wonder about the result. The first semi-Mellin transform has a worm.

If you really want to strictly go for this step (from sum to integral), suggest you write out all in very detail and diligently and use the precise formalism of Perron. The final result in its essence is interesting and I thing probably you will get somthing new. What I found in an own theorem is that $\psi(x) < 3.6757575...$.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't understand what you are trying to saying.

Comment: And what do you mean by $\psi(x)<3.675..$, $\psi$ grows with out bound

Comment: and the $\log$ over the product of all prime?

Comment: What log what primes? Your not making any sense

Comment: I think this is not corresponding to the discussion here. However taking the product over all primes according to Munoz and Garcia (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeProducts.html) and applying $log$.